# gradle android - google services 3.2.0 [ERROR] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform]

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

i have downgraded google services plugin to 3.2.0 inorder for my builds to work sense 3.3.0 is broken.

but when i run the gradle build i get the following error stacktrace:

[ERROR] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:483)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:331)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:91)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(ClassVisitor.java:339)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:112)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:702)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)

let me show you my gradle project details:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    //kotlin version
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.kotlin_ktx_version = '0.3'

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/pt-midtrans/maven" }

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        google()
    }



    project.ext {

        minimumSdkVersion = 16

        supportlib_version = '27.1.1'

        room_version = '1.0.0'

        espresso_version = '3.0.1'

        archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'

        dagger = '2.15'
    }

}

subprojects {
    //todo change this to loop once
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$supportlib_version" //force all versions of support library to be the same. i tried commending out this entire block but that is not the issue
            }
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is my module gradle file (single module application i have, only app):

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minimumSdkVersion
        //check top level build.gradle  file for attributes -
        targetSdkVersion 27
        applicationId "com.mobile.mypackage"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3" //whatever


        testInstrumentationRunner "com.mobile.mypackage.base.MyTestRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions 'tier'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false //for troubleshooting, should set to false in production build
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-fresco.pro', 'proguard-gson.pro', 'proguard-midtrans.pro'
        }

        debugMini {
            //this is a proguarded version of debug build, turn off - InstaRun to use
            initWith debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-fresco.pro', 'proguard-gson.pro', 'proguard-midtrans.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        //for out of memory gc overhead error
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    testOptions {
        //this seems to be absolutely nothing in build tools 25.0.3. after upgrading gradle will check again
        animationsDisabled = true
        execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }

    productFlavors {

        def STRING = "String"
        def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
        def TRUE = "true"
        def FALSE = "false"
        def BASE_ENDPOINT = "BASE_ENDPOINT"


        staging {
            dimension 'tier'
      buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://api.myendpoint.com"'
      versionNameSuffix '-STAGING'
            applicationIdSuffix 'staging'
        }

        labs {
            dimension 'tier'
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false

              buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://api.myendpoint.com"'
              versionNameSuffix '-LABs'
            applicationIdSuffix 'labs'
        }

        prod {
            dimension 'tier'
            buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://api.myendpoint.com"'
          }
    }
}

kapt {
    useBuildCache = false //toggle this to see if it will help
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version") {
    force = true
}
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportlib_version"
implementation("com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version") {
    force = true
}

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

//firebase
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0") {
    //force = true
}
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2") {
   // force = true
}

implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2") {
  //  force = true
}
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0") {
  //  force = true
}
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2") {
  //  force = true
}

//rxjava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'

//square
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12"
implementation 'com.github.ajalt:timberkt:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.rx.idler:rx2-idler:0.9.0' //for espresso

//mosby //some bug in mosby3 and dagger2 preventing me from updating still. i opened a bug with mosby:  https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues/298
implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:viewstate:2.0.1'

//------Architecture Components ------------

//room db
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"

implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"

// Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$archLifecycleVersion"

kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"

//------END Architecture Components ------------

//event Bus
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

//FB
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.32.0'
//implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

//testing
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.9'
androidTestImplementation 'com.github.fabioCollini:DaggerMock:0.8.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'

// Espresso dependencies
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso_version"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso_version"
// androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.0.1'
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:$espresso_version"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:$espresso_version"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espresso_version"

//UI dependencies
implementation 'com.andreabaccega:android-edittext-validator:1.3.4'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation "com.imgix:imgix-java:1.1.10"
implementation 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
implementation 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar' //loading screen
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'//drop down list
implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'//drop down list
implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:recyclerviewheader2:2.0.1'
//implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.1.1' //snap
implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.faruktoptas:FancyShowCaseView:1.0.0'

//data structures
implementation 'com.scalified:tree:0.2.4'

//parcelable
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
//payment gateways
//implementation 'co.omise:omise-android:2.3.+'
implementation 'co.omise:omise-android:2.6.4'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
debugImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.17.0-SANDBOX'
debugMiniImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.17.0-SANDBOX'
releaseImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.17.0'

//fresh chat
implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.3.1'

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
    transitive = true

    //one signal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'

    //retrofit pretty logs
    implementation('com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:2.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    //barcode scanner
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'

    //masking text
    implementation 'com.redmadrobot:inputmask:2.3.0'

    // Analytics
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.0"
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'

    //runtime permissions
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'

    //chrome custom tabs
    implementation 'saschpe.android:customtabs:1.0.9'

    //searching
    implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.+'

    //credit card scanner
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'

    //firebase test orchestrator
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.1'

    //kotlin
    //implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    //kotlin ktx
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$kotlin_ktx_version"

    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //add to bottom of file
```

i tried adding the following boolaen to gradle-properties but its not helping:  android.enableD8.desugaring = true

im . using gradle wrapper 4.4 but also tried 4.6.  instanrun is off. and configure on demand is turned off.  but i tried them both on also.  i toggled D8 compiler but that did not help.

do you think it something to do with Java runtime Environment? i see the following summary error:

```
Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

[image]

its my understanding that in gradle i can use  `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"` and it will [figure out which package version to use](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

removing the dependency on oneSignal sdk resolved this issue:

remove this line from build.gradle:

```
 implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.4'
```

it seems that above dependency works if i remove the following from gradle:

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

**update**: i do not have to remove java 8 features now. i found that if i force all dependencies to be firebase 12.0.1 then it all works.  here is my resolution strategy in top level gradle file:

```
    subprojects {
    //todo change this to loop once
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
          if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms' ||
                    details.requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                details.useVersion(firebase_resolution_version)//firebase_resolution_version being 12.0.1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then go into your build.gradle app file and change all dependecies to be 12.0.1 for com.google.android.gms* and com.google.firebase.*

ensure your using  **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'** also